# Why does comparing using greater than and less than always return true?

Tags: c, logic, operators

I am trying to compare command-line input to check whether or not it is between and including 0 and 2. Am I misunderstanding the &&(and) operator?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  if ((argc >= 0) && (argc <= 2))
    printf("True\n");
  else
    printf("False\n");
  }
```

No matter what value I input, I always get True.

```
[jpuyear]$ ./test 1
True
[jpuyear]$ ./test 0
True
[jpuyear]$ ./test 2
True
[jpuyear]$ ./test 3
True
[jpuyear]$ ./test 4
True
```

Comment: `argc` is the argument _count_.  Not an argument _value_.  Try `if (argc >= 2 && atoi(argv[1]) >= 0 && atoi(argv[1])  <= 2)) printf("True\n");`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Except atoi shouldn't be used for any purpose. Use `strtol`, especially when teaching beginners.

Answer (score 2):

`argc` is the *count* of how many arguments you have.  Each time you enter one argument, so `argc` is 2 (one for the program name and one for the argument passed in) and the condition is true.

`argv` contains the strings which are the actual arguments.  So first make sure that `argc` is at least 2, and if so use `atoi` to convert `argv[1]` to an integer and check that.

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8v5ErMeT6)